# How to find an object which contains a specific string and a number which is the highest number?

Tags: python, aws-cloudformation, boto3

I'm a beginner in Python and I'm trying to use boto (CloudFormation) to list the latest stacks created which contains a string.

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('cloudformation')
stacks = client.list_stacks(
    StackStatusFilter=[
        'CREATE_COMPLETE'
    ]
)

for st in stacks["StackSummaries"]:
    print(st)
```

This is part of the output I get from running the command:

```
{u'StackId': 'arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:AWSACCOUNTID:stack/Company-Dev-31/4d501360-d521-11e7-9aff-50a68a0bca9a', u'StackName': 'Company-Dev-31', u'CreationTime': datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 29, 16, 21, 6, 636000, tzinfo=tzutc()), u'StackStatus': 'CREATE_COMPLETE', u'TemplateDescription': 'Company - Formation of Server Machines @ Oregon (us-west-2)'}
{u'StackId': 'arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:AWSACCOUNTID:stack/Company-Dev-30/4d501360-c231-11e7-8aca-50a68a0bca9a', u'StackName': 'Company-Dev-30', u'CreationTime': datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 29, 16, 21, 6, 644000, tzinfo=tzutc()), u'StackStatus': 'CREATE_COMPLETE', u'TemplateDescription': 'Company - Formation of Server Machines @ Oregon (us-west-2)'}
{u'StackId': 'arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:AWSACCOUNTID:stack/Company-Stg-22/bc2b6c10-d41a-11e7-b1ab-50d5ca789eae', u'StackName': 'Company-Stg-22', u'CreationTime': datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 28, 9, 1, 34, 985000, tzinfo=tzutc()), u'StackStatus': 'CREATE_COMPLETE', u'TemplateDescription': 'Company - Formation of Server Machines @ Oregon (us-west-2)'}
{u'StackId': 'arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:AWSACCOUNTID:stack/Company-Prod-US-API-64/0e85cc00-9602-11e7-8c08-50d5ca0184d2', u'StackName': 'Company-Prod-US-API-64', u'CreationTime': datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 10, 8, 28, 43, 598000, tzinfo=tzutc()), u'StackStatus': 'CREATE_COMPLETE', u'TemplateDescription': 'Company - Formation of Server Machines'}
{u'StackId': 'arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:AWSACCOUNTID:stack/Company-Prod-US-API-63/1ba257c0-9600-11e7-821f-503f20f2ad4a', u'StackName': 'Company-Prod-US-API-63', u'CreationTime': datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 10, 8, 14, 46, 602000, tzinfo=tzutc()), u'StackStatus': 'CREATE_COMPLETE', u'TemplateDescription': 'Company - Formation of Server Machines'}
{u'StackId': 'arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:AWSACCOUNTID:stack/Company-Prod-US-API-61/9252a9d0-2ace-11e7-8eea-503ac9ec2461', u'StackName': 'Company-Prod-US-API-61', u'CreationTime': datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 26, 22, 20, 36, 473000, tzinfo=tzutc()), u'StackStatus': 'CREATE_COMPLETE', u'TemplateDescription': 'Company - Formation of Server Machines'}
{u'StackId': 'arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:AWSACCOUNTID:stack/Company-Prod-US-API-60/1ba83440-2acd-11e7-a0c3-503a90a9c435', u'StackName': 'Company-Prod-US-API-60', u'CreationTime': datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 26, 22, 10, 7, 890000, tzinfo=tzutc()), u'StackStatus': 'CREATE_COMPLETE', u'TemplateDescription': 'Company - Formation of Server Machines'}
```

It seems like the output is already sorted with the newest objects first.

I would like to parse the name of the stack which contains the word "Dev" and where the number is the highest among the rest of the stacks of the same environment (Dev), in this case "Company-Dev-31".

How can it be achieved?

Comment: Add `if 'dev' in st['StackName'].lower():` before the `print` ?

Comment: Thanks! please create an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test if some characters are present by using `in` as follows:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('cloudformation')
stacks = client.list_stacks(
    StackStatusFilter=[
        'CREATE_COMPLETE'
    ]
)

for st in stacks["StackSummaries"]:
    if 'dev' in st['StackName'].lower():
        print(st)
```

This would give you:

```
{u'StackId': 'arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:AWSACCOUNTID:stack/Company-Dev-31/4d501360-d521-11e7-9aff-50a68a0bca9a', u'StackName': 'Company-Dev-31', u'CreationTime': datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 29, 16, 21, 6, 636000), u'StackStatus': 'CREATE_COMPLETE', u'TemplateDescription': 'Company - Formation of Server Machines @ Oregon (us-west-2)'}
{u'StackId': 'arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:AWSACCOUNTID:stack/Company-Dev-30/4d501360-c231-11e7-8aca-50a68a0bca9a', u'StackName': 'Company-Dev-30', u'CreationTime': datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 29, 16, 21, 6, 644000), u'StackStatus': 'CREATE_COMPLETE', u'TemplateDescription': 'Company - Formation of Server Machines @ Oregon (us-west-2)'}
```

Converting first to lowercase has the effect of making the test case insensitive, so `Dev` or `dev` would match.

Answer (score 2):

To add to Martin's answer, you can take the number from each entry containing 'Dev' then use a list comprehension to retrieve the entry with the highest number:

```
numlist = []

for item in st:
    if 'Dev' in item['StackName']:
        num = int(item['StackName'].split('Dev-')[1])
        numlist.append(num)

result = [i for i in st if ('Dev-%s' % max(numlist)) in i['StackName']]

print(result)
```

Giving:

```
[{u'StackId': 'arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:AWSACCOUNTID:stack/Company-Dev-31/4d501360-d521-11e7-9aff-50a68a0bca9a', u'StackName': 'Company-Dev-31', u'CreationTime': datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 29, 16, 21, 6, 636000, tzinfo=tzutc()), u'StackStatus': 'CREATE_COMPLETE', u'TemplateDescription': 'Company - Formation of Server Machines @ Oregon (us-west-2)'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Itai,

first make a sublist with those stacks that have Dev in their names, then sort the resulting list using the Dev number as a key.

```
# make a list of stacks with Dev in stack ID
sublist = [ s for s in stacks if 'Dev' in s['StackId'] ]

# Extract a number from stack ID
REGEX = re.compile("Dev-([0-9]+)")
def extractNum(stack):
    match = REGEX.search(stack['StackId'])
    if match:
        return int(match.group(1))
    else:
        return None

# Sort the stack list in descending order
sublist.sort(key=extractNum, reverse=True)
print(sublist[0])
```

If you wish, it might be compressed to 'one liner', using built-in functions and lambda.

```
REGEX = re.compile("Dev-([0-9]+)")
sublist = sorted(filter(lambda s: 'Dev' in s['StackId'], 
                        stacks),
    key = lambda s: int(REGEX.search(s['StackId']).group(1)),
    reverse = True
    );
```

`filter` makes an iterator that contains only those elements of `stacks` that match the condition

`sorted` makes a sorted list using the specified function that produces the value for ordering.